# class and variable declaration( of same class type)

Tags: c++, class, struct, declaration

Is this declaration correct in c++?

```
class Abc
{
struct xyz x;

};

struct xyz
{
Abc abc;
int instances;
};
```

I receive the following error.
error: field 'x' has incomplete type

So, if I have usecase as above, how do I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this because there is a cyclic dependency between the two types. You can achieve this by using pointer to structure as member and **[forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)**.